# ahk send alternative in bash script

Tags: bash, autohotkey, keypress

I want to achieve in a bash script, that when I press any key (e.g. F5) and then type any word (e.g. "hello world"), regardless of whether I positioned in the terminal, or text-editor or browser...

While I was using Windows, then I used Autohotkey for that.

How could I achieve that with bash script in Linux?

Comment: You probably can't do this in bash alone. An answer might also depend on your desktop environment, so please add that as a tag. By the way: Desktop environments like Cinnamon already allow you to create global shortcuts very easily. Such a shortcut could start your bash script that emulates typing `hello world` (for instance by using `xdotool`). However, https://unix.stackexchange.com seems more appropriate for this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While as @Socowi mentioned, you will likely not be able to do this with bash alone, you can use AutoHotkey Linux alternatives like AutoKey for this.

For your specific question, see [this guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/11/how-to-automate-repetitive-typing-text.html) for setting up and configuring AutoKey on Linux.

More specifically, scroll down to the section labeled "Inserting repetitive text using a hotkey" for how to configure a text-typing hotkey:

> ### Inserting repetitive text using a hotkey
>
> Abbreviations is only one way of inserting text using AutoKey. If you
> prefer, you can also insert text using a keyboard shortcut, which
> doesn't require typing an abbreviation.
>
> To insert some text that you need to type frequently using a keyboard
> shortcut, click the Set button next to Hotkey, then click Press to Set
> in the newly opened window, and press the key combination you want to
> use for this phrase:
>
> [image: AutoKey set hotkey screenshot]
>
> Make sure you use a hotkey that's not already in use or else it may
> not work / it will interfere with the already set hotkey. To try this
> out, set it to something like Ctrl + F1 (which shouldn't be set by the
> system at least).
>
> Remember to click the Save button in the AutoKey toolbar after setting
> the phrase hotkey, or else the changes won't have any effect. Now try
> it out: focus a text editor, some text field in a web form, etc., and
> press the hotkey you've set in AutoKey - the Testing AutoKey text
> expansion on Linux phrase should be automatically inserted as soon as
> you press the keyboard shortcut.